# When backing up files and folders, include or exclude thumbs.db?

Tags: backup, file-transfer, file-management, photos, thumbs.db

When backing up individual files and folders (as opposed to creating volume images), are there any reasons to intentionally include or exclude `thumbs.db` files?

The sources of the files are Android and Windows devices.

The destination is external drives with folders that may later be restored to Windows devices.

Obviously, one reason to *not* backup `thumbs.db` files is to save some space on the backup medium.  Are there any other reasons to intentionally **include** or **exclude** `thumbs.db` files in backups?

Comment: Thumbs.db is just a cache of thumbnails of images in the source folder. Given Windows will regenerate them in a very short space of time, I would forgo backing them up. IMHO it's personal preference.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thank you. That's my understanding and inclination as well. Before I choose to not backup hundreds (thousands?) of thumbs.db files, I want to verify with the community that it's a smart decision and that I'm not making a mistake.  Feel free to post your comment as an answer (perhaps with a few more details) if you like.

Comment: @Gronostaj has it covered.

Answer (score 4):

`thumbs.db` is a thumbnail cache store. As with all caches, it can be deleted safely, because all of its content can be generated from original files. Cache is only a performance optimization.